# Matplotlib: Spaces in between hexagons in hexbin plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making hexbin plots using the following Python script:

```py
## object of Pitch class
pitch = Pitch(
    line_color="#747474", pitch_color="#222222", orientation="vertical", half=True, plot_arrow=False
)

## plot the pitch
fig, ax = pitch.create_pitch()

## color-map
cmap = [
    "#222222", "#2A2224", "#3A2027", "#421F28", 
    "#54202B", "#65202E", "#782231", "#892433", "#9B2838",
    "#AC2B3A", "#BE2F3E", "#CF3341", "#E13746"
]
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cmap)

## make hexbins
hexbin = ax.hexbin(
    68 - shots_data['Y'], shots_data['X'], zorder=3, cmap=cmap,
    extent=(0, 68, 52, 104), gridsize=25, bins=13
)
```

It is generating the following output:

[image]

Now I want to have small spaces in-between each hexagon but I don't know what to add in the script to make it happen. Can somebody help?

Comment: I found [this](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) for you to learn about the properties of a hexagonal grid. Downvoting as you haven't made a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I ask, why do you need spaces between the hexagons? I would expect that adding spaces between hexagons would make it more difficult to understand the hexbin plot.

Comment: Well I found a design in which there were spaces between hexagons and trying to make the same.

Comment: @Mandera sir, that's a lot of reading and I don't want to dive in deep with the mathematics part, just need a solution in Python. Any help is appreciated

Comment: @slothfulwave612 I'm sorry I assumed you were here to learn

Comment: No problem sir, I got the answer, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a white edge color, and some fine line width:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors

np.random.seed(0)
n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 4))

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(["#222222", "#2A2224", "#3A2027", "#421F28", "#54202B", "#65202E", "#782231",
                              "#892433", "#9B2838", "#AC2B3A", "#BE2F3E", "#CF3341", "#E13746"])
hb = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=50, bins='log', cmap=cmap, ec='white', lw=0.5)
ax.margins(x=-0.1, y=-0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks brother. Just changed ec="#222222" and lw=3 and got the result.